# Why does ServiceStack v3.9.28 nuget not contain SqlServerStorage class for MiniProfiler

Tags: servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

I used the nuget command to get the ServiceStack dll's. The 3.9.28 I have does not contain the SqlServerStorage class in the MiniProfiler namespace. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack includes a port of MiniProfiler that's integrated to work with ServiceStack. To remove conflicts ServiceStack's port is kept under the `ServiceStack.MiniProfiler` namespace at which place you will find the [SqlServerStorage.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/MiniProfiler/Storage/SqlServerStorage.cs) class.